# Background picture doesn't fullscreen on iOS

Tags: html, css, ios, background

I want to have my background picture fill out the whole screen but I can't find a solution to fix my problem. Would be cool if someone could give me a solution for all mobile devices.

This is what my screen would look like now:
[image: screenshot]

I tried many things. Here is my current code:

```
html {
    background: url('/path/to/img') no-repeat center center fixed !important;
    background-size: cover !important;
    height: 100%;
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
html { background-image: ... 
    no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%; }
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately this doesn't work either. Now the picture ist cut off at the middle. I even tried it with other pictures in other formats...

Comment: So how I have mine set up looks like this:  body {
  color: white; 
  background-image: url(/img/20210719_123218.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}   and it covers the screen on all device sizes. Keep in mind that when you add more content to the page the background will continue to stretch itself making it more zoomed in. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: This doesn't work too. Still cut off and the edges still white. It doesn't seem to relate to the content. It looks like the viewport ends when the screen starts to curve. Could the format (2048x2048px) effect it? I don't think so because I already  tried it with an apple background picture.

Comment: In the head tag make sure there is a meta tag that says:

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />.

If this doesn't help then I regret that I am out of solutions without being able to see the problem it is hard to tell. Good luck, I hope you get the proper help.

Comment: Doesn't work either sorry. Anyways, thanks for your input!